# Why can I view my data in TestDisk but not otherwise? How can I recover the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, testdisk

A few days ago I was working on my computer and my hard drive decided it was time to say goodbye; the screen froze, and when I tried booting my computer it failed.

I take the drive out, put it into an enclosure, and try to look at what was going on through another computer.
All I see is "SYSTEM_DRV (F:)".

I then run [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and a "Local Disk (G:)" appears in "My Computer" that I can't access. There is now also "Lenovo_Recovery (H:)".

Back in TestDisk,

- I selected the hard drive I want to look at and hit "Proceed".
- I then select the "Intel/PC partition table" type and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- I then hit "Analyse". I see three partitions and hit "Quick Search". I see one Primary bootable and two more Primary partitions.

When I go to the section I can't view in "My Computer (G:)", where all my data and files are, I can see all the files there. However, I can't view or do anything to that partition in "My Computer".

When I try to access Drive "G:" through `cmd`, it takes a long while and then spits back "The device is not ready".

I then hit get to "Write" and I write a partition table. It tells me I would have to restart, so I do. I load the disk again and it's the same story.

What is the reason behind this? Is there a way to recover the hard drive?

Comment: I recommend you use TestDisk to copy the files off to another physical disk or storage device, then worry about why it is happening, because if your hard drive is physically failing you may not have much time.